# Modifying a program for something then changing it back

Tags: javascript, c#, python, robotics, notepad

I was wondering if anyway had any input on whether it would be possible to write a program that automatically modified certain lines of a program so it could be used in a touch-up program that does not allow that type of data. Then I would like to modify if back to it's original form afterwards. So basically remove offset info to touch-up points  on a robot and then add that offset data back into the program. The program I will be modifying is in regular notepad. The original file type is ls I believe. If anyone has any input into how this can be accomplished please I am open to all suggestions. I am decent at c# but would be willing use and learn any language I needed for the project.

Comment: Looks like what you want can be achieved by writing some `if` statements.

Comment: pass in a vairable and change the code based on that

Comment: like the answers above, just use parameters/arguments and check with `if` and thats it